# how do I share photos on the web with iPhoto / iCloud?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I have a new Mac (Mountain Lion) with iPhoto '11.

I want to share photos on the web.  In the past, I would launch iWeb and build a little photo album web page.  My understanding was that if I subscribed to .Mac/MobileMe I could share my iWeb page that way, but instead I always FTPed my web page to my own web site.

On my new Mac, I see that iWeb no longer exists.  In iPhoto I discovered there's something called "photo streams".  I signed into "iCloud", I dragged some photos to my "photo stream", and it appears the photos are now online (unless I'm not understanding something).

I signed into www.icloud.com, but I don't see any photos there.

QUESTION: What am I missing, or, What is the "correct" way to share photos on the web with iPhoto '11?

Answer (score 1):

iCloud is not a replacement for MobileMe--those great-looking photo albums are a thing of the past.

Photostream shares photos between Macs, iPads and iPhones, automatically and pretty instantaneously — unless of course you turn it off -- in a separate album from the device's camera roll.

Apple no longer provides a way to share photos on the web. Mores the pity.

Edit: iOS 6 offers Shared Photo Streams on iCloud.com.

> Shared Photo Streams allow you to post and share photos to a Photo
>   Stream album hosted by iCloud. The photos stored there don't count
>   against your iCloud storage allotment, and will work over Wi-Fi and
>   cellular data. You're able to share photos with fellow iOS users as
>   well as by creating an iCloud.com Shared Photo Stream album for
>   non-iOS users.

See the rest of the How-To on [CNET](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57508640-285/how-to-create-a-shared-photo-stream-album-on-ios-6/).

Comment: The Shared Photo Stream seems to include a web version, though: http://www.apple.com/icloud/features/photo-stream.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, but there is a "On The Web" feature on the page @Thilo linked to.  How do I do that?

Comment: Also, turns out there's an "Export" feature that will export photos to a HTML photo album, but it's literally a plain HTML page -- looks like crap.